# Determine if {p,q,r} ⊢ α∨β

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

p,q,r are propositional variables, and θ,ζ,ξ are formal theorems of propositional logic.

α=θ→[p∧[q→(ζ→(ξ∧r))]];
β=p→(q∧r)

I can't understand how a set of variables can prove two statements.

Comment: P,q,r occur into formula beta

Comment: What is the truth value of beta when p,q,e are all tre?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA beta  and alpha are true when p,q,r are true

Comment: The proof is straightforward, using basic rules: from premise q and r we have $(q \land r)$ by Conjunction Introduction, and so on.